# Error Downloading http://downloads.arduino.cc/packages/packages_index.json

Tags: library

I managed to update the library but getting error "Error Downloading http://downloads.arduino.cc/packages/packages_index.json" when updating the *Board Manager*. I switched the proxy to no proxy instead of automatic. Anyone can help me?

Comment: use your computer web browser to see if the URL is valid

Answer (score 0):

The URL is wrong, and should read:

```
https://downloads.arduino.cc/packages/package_index.json
```

Note that "package_index" is in the singular, not the plural.

Check what you have in the "Additional Boards Manager URLs:" section of Preferences.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the fix that worked for me is to directing the jvm to use the Windows Certificate Store instead of the ancient cacerts file that comes with java 1.8. This may also help people behind a Cisco Umbrella filter.

One does this by adding the following lines to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\arduino.l4j.ini" (note, you will need to open a text editor as an administrator, then open the file in question, in order to edit it):

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=NUL
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=Windows-ROOT
```

[I found this answer here](http://You%20can%20also%20try%20directing%20the%20jvm%20to%20use%20the%20Windows%20Certificate%20Store%20instead%20of%20the%20ancient%20cacerts%20file%20that%20comes%20with%20java%201.8.%20This%20may%20also%20help%20people%20behind%20a%20Cisco%20Umbrella%20filter.%20One%20does%20this%20by%20adding%20the%20following%20lines%20to%20%22C:%5CProgram%20Files%20(x86)%5CArduino%5Carduino.l4j.ini%22%20(note,%20you%20will%20need%20to%20open%20a%20text%20editor%20as%20an%20administrator,%20then%20open%20the%20file%20in%20question,%20in%20order%20to%20edit%20it):%20-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=NUL%20-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=Windows-ROOT)